# ngcordova camera images in a list from array

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I need to push my `base64` string into an empty array so that I can make use of it in $http post.i don' understand when i have made mistake. when i use chome://inspect/#device i get ERROR:-No Content-Security-Policy meta tag found. Please add one when using the cordova-plugin-whitelist plugin and after photo was taken i get net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND but i can list my photos

**HTML**

```
<ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
    <h1 class="title">OB3 SNAPSHOT</h1>
    <button class="button button-clear button-large ion-ios-camera" style="align:right" ng-click="takePicture()"></button>
</ion-header-bar>
<ion-content>
    <img ng-show="imgURI !== undefined" ng-src="{{imgURI}}">
    <img ng-show="imgURI === undefined" ng-src="http://placehold.it/300x300">
    <!--<button class = "button" ng-click="takePicture()">Take Picture</button>-->
    <ul class="list">
        <li class="item" ng-repeat="i in myImage">
            <img ng-src="{{baseURL+i}}" ng-click="clickImage()">
        </li>
    </ul>
</ion-content>
```

**AngularJS**

```
exampleApp.controller("ExampleController", function($scope, $cordovaCamera) {
    $scope.myImage = [];
    $scope.baseURL = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,';

    $scope.clickImage = function() {
        var postObject = {
            data: {
                "width": 32,
                "height": 32,
                "mimetype": "image/png",
                "name": "Image",
                "bindaryData": $scope.myImage[0]
            }
        }

        $http.post(" url",
                postObject)
            .success(function(response) {
                $scope.names = response.response.data;
                console.log(response);
                console.log(response.response.data);
            })

        .error(function(response) {
            console.log(response);
            alert('post is error');
        });
    };


    $scope.takePicture = function() {
        navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, {
            quality: 75,
            targetWidth: 320,
            targetHeight: 320,
            destinationType: 0
        });

        function onSuccess(imageData) {
            $scope.imgURI = imageData;
            $scope.myImage.push($scope.imgURI);
            $scope.$apply();
        }

        function onFail(message) {
            alert('Failed because: ' + message);
        }

    };
});
```

Comment: What do you mean "you can't push the base64 string into the array"? Elaborate on that (preferably with more code as well as to where you are trying to access your array)

Comment: i push imgURI to array but i get data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData; i don't need to push data:image/jpeg;base64, i just need to push imageData alone.

Comment: please check out my updated question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the  pushing  of **$scope.imgURI** is working perfectly.But your view is not updated.please take two photos.Then you can understand your problem.By adding **`$scope.$apply(`**) will resolve your issue

Just try this code,

**Controller**

```
$scope.myImage = [];
$scope.baseURL = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,';
$scope.takePhoto = function() {
     navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, {
         quality: 75,
         targetWidth: 320,
         targetHeight: 320,
         destinationType: 0
     });

     function onSuccess(imageData) {
         $scope.imgURI = imageData;
         $scope.myImage.push($scope.imgURI);
         $scope.$apply();
     }

     function onFail(message) {
         alert('Failed because: ' + message);
     }

};
```

**HTML**

```
<button ng-click="takePhoto()">Capture</button>
<li ng-repeat="i in myImage">
    <img ng-src="{{baseURL+i}}">
</li>
```

**[Refer](https://blog.nraboy.com/2014/09/use-android-ios-camera-ionic-framework/)**

Comment: yes you are right but can you please help me to display in image format not as base64

Comment: just add this line  <img ng-show="imgURI !== undefined" ng-src="{{imgURI}}">

Comment: please check my updated answer.It will display the  image that you took.

Comment: i have added but i need to display each and every picture that i take in a list formate

Comment: Hi muhsin, when we push over base64 string to array i am getting $scope.imgURI = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData; in list when we did not use ng-src="{i}".

Comment: i need that imageData only it only contain the base64 string so i need that only to be pushed to array, because i need to send it to serve in base64 fromate not with that sting before can you help me

Comment: what does baseURL+i does please can you explain me

Comment: baseURL is the format of your image [here it is 'data:image/jpeg;base64,'].

Comment: You need to push all the images to array.Right?

Comment: So i added imgData in to array

Comment: In order to display all the image ,we need format and src of that image

Comment: Shall we start a chat room?

Comment: when i use chrome://inspect/#device i am getting ERROR:-No Content-Security-Policy meta tag found. Please add one when using the cordova-plugin-whitelist plugin.

Comment: after i add <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src: 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">

Comment: i am geting chrome it self